# How can I create my APK locally which has signature compatible with my app on Playstore (which uses Google's app signing)?

Tags: android, google-play, signing, android-app-signing

I have Google App signing enabled for my app.
I created an APK and signed it using my keystore file and uploaded it to devConsole. Google then signed the APK again using Google's App signing which it then sent to users on Playstore.

1. I downloaded and installed the APK from Playstore (which contains Google's App signing signature).
2. I downloaded App signing certificate from devConsole -> App signing -> App signing certificate
3. I added the certificate to my current keystore file using below command:

> keytool -importcert -file [app_signing_certificate] -keystore
>   [current_keystore_file]

4. I created release APK using the new keystore which got generated in step 3
5. Now when I try to upgrade this new APK over the APK which I installed from Playstore, I get an error.

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package
>   xyz signatures do not match previously installed
>   version; ignoring!]

I want to know what needs to be done to create an APK locally which matches the signature of the one downloaded from Playstore.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it. For Google Play App signing, only Google can sign the APKs.

As it says on [the help pages](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423):

> - Certificate: A certificate contains a public key as well as some extra identifying information about who owns the key.

The app signing certificate you get from Google is just the public key information that can be used to verify the signature. It doesn't let you sign apps. When you add it to your keystore you just get the ability to verify.

This doesn't mean you are stuck though. Why do you need to sign it yourself?

- if it is just for using a server side API, then most APIs will let you add more than one signature, and you can use your development key as well as the Google key as authorized
- if it is so you can quickly iterate during development, this can be done using Google Play [Internal Test tracks](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) which lets you send an internal test version to developers or QA very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. @Nick Fortescue

Consider a scenario where a user is on our 2-way signed build (installed from Playstore). User is facing some issue which needs code level debugging on that device. So we have to move the user to debug build (but without uninstalling the previous build)

One way is to create build locally with "debuggable true". But as per your above answer, we cannot create APK locally with same signing.
Another way is to download derived APK from Playstore, but Playstore does not allow uploading debug builds.

What can we do in this situation?

Comment: Yes, that is tricky. Fundamentally, Google play does not want to expose users to debug APKs because it puts them in danger. I can see two options: 1) debug through log statements, and get the user on an internal test track. 2) if it is so severe you need debugging, back up the users local storage, uninstall the play version, and fresh install the debuggable version. Neither is ideal, but you should almost never be in a situation where you need to give a debuggable APK to a production user.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the actual signing key from Google.  Which I don't think you can get, so you can't.

Comment: Correct. One of the goal of using App signing by Google Play with a different upload keystore is not having the keystore laying around on your machine. For local development, you should test with debug keys. When you want to test a release, you can use a test track in the Play Console.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan  when I add the "App signing certificate" (which I get from devConsole -> App signing) to my keystore file, that does not make it equivalent to the actual signing from Google? What is the difference between the two?