# How to update playstore apk with a signed apk without losing play store app data?

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, mobile, release

I have an app released on Play Store and in way to test the new updates I want to run my signed apk without losing the application data of Play Store app installed on the phone.
I just need to update the existing installed app and not deleting it then reinstalling the new apk.

If I try to run the Signed apk I will get the warning [the device already has an application with the same package...] but I don't want to delete the existing play store app.

Is there any way I can update my existing Play Store apk with the new one by running the apk from android studio and without losing play store app data?

Thanks,

Comment: if they are signed with the same key you should be able to just install over it

Comment: It's also possible that you have play store signing enabled, you can check that on the console - app integrity, if it's enabled, you will probably need to drop your apk to internal app sharing or testing to actually download it without losing any data; Here's a post which says you can't do it locally, but it's worth looking on your own if you really need it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821432/how-can-i-create-my-apk-locally-which-has-signature-compatible-with-my-app-on-pl

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a closed test on the play store and add yourself as the only tester. You can download an update from the playstore just as your users will. It also doesnt take too long for the new version to be displayed.

You can do that from this link: https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing/